# Automatically launch java server program with AWS autoscaling

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I recently found out about AWS' autoscaling feature and I would like to incorporate it into my next game. I couldn't find if it is possible to automatically run my java program on new instance launch. Is this automatically done when I create the AMI image? How can I make this happen? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to run Java programs on EC2 launches.

For that you can use user data scripts and configure them in your launch configurations

For more details   [click here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)